# is there a way to convert a small image to big image proportionally using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote some business logic that removes unnecessary areas of an image using HTML5 canvas and produces another image. The result image is small in size like 500x300. My requirement is to `generate high resolution image from that small image`.

I am using drawImage method for removing unnecessary parts

```
context.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh);
```

Is there something I can do to tweak the canvas to generate high resolution image?

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, humans have evolved. You can also prove your try for evolution by writing a comment for downvote.

Comment: By making an image smaller you are removing information. When you "scale up" a small image you will lose quality as something has to make a guess as what to use for the new pixels and that will never be as good as the original large image. Even dedicated programs like Photoshop will lose quality. You will loose even more with the Canvas.

Comment: @JonP Thanks. Yeah I was aware of that, just posted to check if someone has solution for this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
context.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw * 2, sh * 2, 0, 0, sw, sh);
```

Use this to multiply the image size by 2

Comment: Thanks but It should for last args `sw` and `sh`. Problem with this is reduced quality.

Comment: You can't have a good quality if the starting image is too small